# Number of clusters error in kmeans clustering

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, k-means

I can only have 5 clusters. I want to have 6 clusters. The code is giving me the following error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

for the following line:

```
plt.plot(X[i][0], X[i][1], colors[labels[i]], markersize = 10)
```

I don't know what is going on. Please help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I found the solution. It was an easy fix !! I forgot to add an extra color.

Comment: I suggest you delete this question, or provide a more in-depth detailed question, or your question will have no use on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `colors` array is large enough.

Also, learn to read error messages and traces and perform basic debugging task to understand your error.

Obviously, the error here was in plotting, not in kmeans. You could have checked how many clusters kmeans found, and this would have been much easier to find.